# Asus router cloud double NAT

Tags: router, nat

I'm building my personal cloud based on Asus routers. I would like to connect a 1TB hard drive to this router and switch it on/off remotely with a phone. So far so good, everything works fine, but I've run into trouble setting up this Asus RT-N14U router.

It throws a double NAT error and I have no idea how to fix it. I cannot change any settings of my network. I can only use my LAN connection and that's it.

[image: Error message from router admin panel]

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's your overall network setup look like? If this isn't the primary router, it should be in access point mode.

Comment: so if I will put my router into access point mode, my cloud will work ?

Comment: I don't know. It could work but I need to know if there's another router in front.

Comment: I think they are. Maybe even more than one, but I don't have chance check it physically and have no idea how to do it with PC

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP gave you a private WAN IP  address, try reaching them out and ask for a public WAN IP address - that should help.